# getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) Passes without WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android

I'm returning the external files directory for API 23 and below.

I want to check that the media is mounted, however this test is always passed, although the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not yet declared in the manifest.

I'm not sure, but I thought the test should fail for API 18 and below if the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not declared/enabled?

A permission denied exception is then thrown when trying to access this directory.

```
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
{
    return getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/update_files";
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests that `getExternalStorageState` requires any permissions.

Comment: But if permission is denied I would have thought the MEDIA_MOUNTED check would fail?

Comment: `A permission denied exception is then thrown when trying to access this directory.` Ok. But the code you posted does not throw that exception. Confusing post.

Comment: _"But if permission is denied I would have thought the MEDIA_MOUNTED check would fail? "_ Why? You're only asking for the state of the external storage; not reading or writing any data from/to it.

Comment: My interpretation of the MEDIA_MOUNTED check would be that if the app does not have permission to read or write to the external storage then how can it read the media is mounted, surely permission should be denied on the check?

Comment: it doesn't read anything. it just detects if it's there or not. If you wanted to get a list of files or create a new one, then it would be a case of reading/writing to external storage

Comment: Ok, so it will detect that it's there even if it's not usable (read/write)?

Comment: The external storage is being used to launch an APK file - I understand that this has to be from external storage for API 23 and below. 

I assume that if the external storage is unmounted, then I won't be able to launch the package installer?

Comment: External storage is always mounted. You dont have to check it.